# Grails HQL (positional params) query for null timestamp -- strange typecast error

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, jdbc, hql

**Grails domain property:** java.sql.Timestamp dateInvoiced

**postgresql column:**      date_invoiced    timestamp without time zone

**My Query:**

```
BrokerageOrder.executeQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM BrokerageOrder d WHERE d.dateInvoiced IS ?",[null])
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp  
   without time zone = bytea
   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add   
   explicit type casts. Position: 133
```

**Question:** how do I fix this? Why does it think my null is a bytea?

Thank you, Jeff.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for null or does [null] represent a parameter that can be null?

Comment: I am looking for all records where the date_invoiced is null. Grails Docs: Book.executeQuery(String query, List positionalParams)

Comment: Change `WHERE d.dateInvoiced IS ?",[null])` to `WHERE d.dateInvoiced IS  null")`

Comment: Yes, that will work, but I am trying to use positional parameters to prevent sql injection attacks. The above code is just an example. I really construct hql queries based upon the user's input. I could change my code to construct a special case for nulls,  but I think the syntax should work -- maybe it is a bug or my grails/hibernate is not setup to handle properties of type java.sql.Timestamp correctly.

Comment: You would worry about [sql injection attacks](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#securingAgainstAttacks) if you are dynamically placing values in the query parameters. In your case you it will be hard coded to `null` as mentioned by @JamesKleeh I do not think there should be any concern about sql injection.

Comment: From my experience the positional parameters in HQL can never be null.